# In C# deserialize simple JSON object into a list of integers

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I keep finding examples of more complex JSON data and so far nothing for such a simple object. (note: this is .NET not Javascript)

```
{"Ids":[5,6,7,8,9,10]}
```

I don't want to create a class, all I want is a simple List a simple list of the Ids so that I can loop over them later in the code.

This does not work:

```
int[] ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(message.Message);
```

Nor does this:

```
List<int> ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(message.Message);
```

I get errors like "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object ... because the type requires a JSON array..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `int[]` nor `List<int>` represent your json structure, you need to introduce a class to hold `Ids` array property:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize to it:

```
var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(message.Message);
```

Another option is to parse your json as `JObject` and deserialize property value:

```
var ids = JObject.Parse(message.Message)["Ids"].ToObject<int[]>();
```

Comment: That second option worked like a charm. Thanks! Glad to see someone is willing to help those of us who don't have all the answers.,

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko was glad to help!